# Pig latin load from S3 (folder expansion)

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-pig

I am trying to use load with data source as S3 bucket.

```
load s3n://hourly-logprocessing/{2013090100,2013100501}/??????_0.gz' using some loader()
```

does not work.

```
load s3n://hourly-logprocessing/{201309????}/??????_0.gz using some loader()
```

does not work.

I get this exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path
>   from an empty string
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:91)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.(Path.java:99)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.(Path.java:58)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.listStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1418)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globPathsLevel(FileSystem.java:1602)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatusInternal(FileSystem.java:1539)

It only works when i use a single folder.

```
load s3n://some-folder/2013090100/??????_0.gz
```

How does pig expand. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, I didn't try your examples, o lazy me, but this works for my 'load' statements:
  's3n://SOME_BUCKET/20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-23-*.mystuff_v14*'
- don't forget single quotes after the load command (which is missing in your examples)